# how to gather all the infomation in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a column of letters (column E) and text column (G).
I'm seeking for a formula to lookup the text values for the individual letters typed into a cell separated by a line end (alt+enter).

I tried using Index and Match to synthesize the information, but couldn't get it to work.

Sample data:

|  | E | F | G |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **1** | A |  | Need |
| **2** | B |  | Some |
| **3** | C |  | One |
| **4** | D |  | To |
| **5** | E |  | Help |
| **6** | F |  | With |
| **7** | O |  | The |
| **8** | D |  | Problem |
| **9** | Z |  | ASAP |
| **10** |  |  |  |
| **11** | A Z |  |  |

Comment: Not sure what the problem is.  You've got A, B, C, D, E, F, Z and AZ.  You need to solve AZ.... what does that mean?

Comment: Do you want to see `NEED ASAP` in cell G11, is that your question? Because in that case, you might need to be able to split the content of cell E11 in single characters, for which I believe you'll need VBA.

Answer (score 0):

This formula arrange all the cells content vertically in one cell

```
=TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10),FALSE,E1:E9)
```

You have to check the cell's Format cells -> Alignment -> Wrap cells

Answer (score 0):

`=TRIM(CONCAT(REPT(G1:G9&" ",EXACT(TEXTSPLIT(E11,CHAR(10)),E1:E9))))`

[image]

I think in older Excel versions this requires being entered with `ctrl+shift+enter`.

This could work for multiple cells at once in Office 365:
`=BYROW(IFNA(TEXTSPLIT(TEXTAFTER(CHAR(10)&E11:E12,CHAR(10),SEQUENCE(,99)),CHAR(10)),""),LAMBDA(b,TRIM(CONCAT(REPT(G1:G9&" ",EXACT(b,E1:E9))))))`

(change `99` to the maximum number of separated strings that can be found in any of the cells).

Answer (score 0):

I had prefer using the <kbd>FILTER()</kbd> function as it seems from your existing sample data in the OP you got some duplicate entries for in `Column E`

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>G11</kbd>

```
=TEXTJOIN(" ",,FILTER(G1:G9,1-ISNA(XMATCH(E1:E9,TEXTSPLIT(E11,CHAR(10))))))
```

---

The above formula needs to fill down, hence before filling down ensure to lock the references i.e. you need to make the ranges absolute, however you can do it for a whole array using single dynamic array formula, also there is a character limitations while using <kbd>TEXTJOIN()</kbd> need to take care of that as well.

---

[image]

---

```
=BYROW(E11:E12,LAMBDA(α, TEXTJOIN(" ",,FILTER(G1:G9,1-ISNA(XMATCH(E1:E9,TEXTSPLIT(α,CHAR(10))))))))
```

---